# При подключении maven к проекту перестал работать post xhr запрос JAVA

Tags: javascript, java, maven, xhr

Сервлет обработки пост запроса, должен выводить Json строку в консоль

```
 @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/add")
public class Add extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        resp.setContentType("application/json");
        resp.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        String jsonString = req.getParameter("param");
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }
}
```

index.jsp форма из двух полей и кнопки submit

```
 <%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>$Title$</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form method="post" onsubmit="run();">
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <input type="text" id="surname"><br>
    <input type="submit">
  </form>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function run() {
      var name = document.getElementById("name");
      var surname = document.getElementById("surname");
      var json = JSON.stringify({
        name:name,surname:surname,
      })
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open("post", "/add");
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.send("param=" + json);
    }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Код деплоится и работает, но сервлет отвечает ошибкой 404, без maven этот код работает, но мне необходи maven для дальнейшей работы.
[image: структура]

Comment: На каком сервере разворачиваете приложение? Приложите WEB.xml. И в pom.xml не хватает <package>war</package>, попробуйте добавить.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно, проблема была в пакетировании, проект заработал, когда  я добавил в pom.xml <packaging>war</packaging> и немного изменил структуру проекта(создал директорию webapp в src.main и перенес в созданную директрию WEB-INF с web.xml ). Сервер  apache tomcat.